# rxJava: composing single with completable and return single

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

my steps are:

1. create a single value x - may be a little cpu intensive
2. use value x to perform IO operation. this already returns `Completable`
3. return x

so i wanted to do sth like this:

```
Single<Integer> result = 
             Single.fromCallable(() -> generate_x)
                .COMPOSE_WITH_COMPLETABLE(x -> method_that_returns_completable(x))
                .map(x -> x + 1) // i still need x here
```

how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

```
single.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Single<? extends Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Single<? extends Integer> call(final Integer integer) {
            return completable.toSingle(new Func0<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call() {
                    return integer;
                }
            });
        }
    })
```